# Want file rename script to add number at end with fixed length

Tags: bash, shell

I have some files with the same extensions:

```
 foo.tif
 bar.tif
 baz.tif
```

I would like to rename them in the following format:

```
 foo_0001.tif
 foo_0002.tif
 etc.
```

I have the following BASH command to rename them:

```
$ c=0; for file in $(ls -rt); do let c=${c}+1; mv "${file}" "foo_${c}.${file#*
 .}"; done
```

This gives me:

```
 foo_1.tif
 foo_2.tif
 foo_3.tif ...
```

What I would like is :

```
 foo_0001.tif
 foo_0002.tif
  etc.
```

Edit: here is the final working script:

```
 $ c=0; ls -rt | while read -r file; do ((++c));  mv "${file}" "$(printf 'foo_%04d.%s' "$c" "${file#*.}")"; done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `printf` with a format specifier:

```
c=0
while read -r file; do 
    ((++c))
    mv "${file}" "$(printf 'test_%04d.%s' "$c" "${file#*.}")"
done < <(ls -rt)
```

The approach using a `while read` loop is slightly safer than what you had originally but the usual advice regarding [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) applies. Be careful!

You can actually combine the two lines inside the loop by replacing `"$c"` with `"$((++c))"`. The double quotes are a little paranoid in this case but they don't do any harm.

Based on your comment, it sounds like you might not be using bash. If that's the case, you can use a pipe instead: `ls -rt | while read -r file; do`.

Comment: Thanks. I have a random list of files with extension .tif.  I want to rename them to   test_001.tif,  test_002.tif, etc.  Sorry that I wasnt clear about this.

Comment: By the way, I am doing this on windows, using the bash shell provided by my git distribution.

Comment: Great. Thanks for accepting my answer. It may be helpful to add some of the additional detail that you've provided in the comments into your question.

Comment: My pleasure. You really earned that one :)

Answer (score 2):

```
do
   let ++c
   d=`printf '%04d' $c`
   mv "${file}" foo_$d
done
```